# Objects move out of collection upon disabling collection

Tags: collections

I don't know what's causing this. When I disable a collection, the objects automatically move out of the collection and stay visible. Once I enable the collection again, they move back into the collection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can u please show us a screenshot (before/after)?

Comment: there's not much to show except the objects automatically moving out of the collection once the collection is disabled.

Comment: Make sure objects aren't part of both of those collections. You can see which collections they belong to in Properties editor > Object > Collections

Comment: so if they are in two or more collections the object wont disappear unless both are disabled? thank you.